How to upgrade Node.JS Apollo Server connection to HTTPS or HTTP2?
How do I upgrade the connection to HTTP or H2?
I am running an apollo server and would like to be able to upgrade to a secure connection. I already generated self-signed certificates. Here is the code of my server.js file.
const {ApolloServer} = require("apollo-server");
const { resolvers } = require("./graphql/resolvers");
const FileSystem = require("node:fs/promises");

//Define function
async function startServer(){
  //Read file as text
  const typeDefs = await FileSystem.readFile("./graphql/type-defs.graphql",{
    encoding: 'utf-8',
  });
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });
  
  server.listen(8080).then(({url})=>{
    console.log(`The API is running at ${url}`);
  });
}
//Call the start server function
startServer();

